# Why has my Pokemon Go avatar become super large?

Tags: pokemon-go

My Pokemon Go avatar is really large. I've tried signing in/out but it hasn't changed.

Is there a way to change it?
I've even tried deleting and reinstalling app but that also didn't worked 
I'm unable to upload a pic as I'm new and don't know how to do it but I'm only able see legs of my avatar on my iPhone nothing else.
Pls can anyone help I'm really eager to play my favourite game again

Comment: The latest update seems to have zoomed in the perspective. Roads seem bigger as well. I'm curious as to whether this has changed the range of the circle in which you can interact with things...

Comment: Can you add a picture for reference? You say "Super large" when in perspective, it already was.

Comment: Zoom out by double tapping, then drag.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you just played in de 0.29.3. 
Just update your POgo and then you should be able to play
(that worked for me)

Comment: Can you please tell me in detail

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to guess that you updated your Pokemon go and then tried to revert back to a previous version. When you were using the updated version you probably change your avatar appearance to the new clothing style. If so the older version of the app will not run correctly and show a large Avatar standing in water. What you need to do is reinstall the new updated version and change your appearance back to any of the original outfits. Then you can uninstall the new version, and reinstall the older version. Login, problem solved. This same issue frustrated me for a good while. The updated version does not run well on my phone so I reverted back to a previous version. However I change my outfit within the new version. I was then getting the same problem. Follow my advice above and your issue should be solved